# Reduce wear of SDD / EXT4 / Frequent overwrites of files

Tags: linux, cache, ssd

I'd like to configure GNU/Linux in a way that the wear of the solid-state disk (SSD) is reduced as much as possible.

Setting: Some programs are frequently ran that overwrite small debug output files (to /tmp) many times a second, and it makes sense to cache the writes in memory until the file becomes stable. Data loss of the recent changes (since the last longer idling period of the system) in case of a loss of power is acceptable.

There is no swap partition/swap file. The SSD is the only hard disk of the system. There is a single partition for "/" on the SSD using ext4. The system runs Ubuntu Linux 17.10. Rewriting the programs to be ran to not cause so much wear would of course be an option, but I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: Putting `/tmp` in tmpfs is a great start (and I don't know why Ubuntu hasn't already done this).

Answer (score 2):

You do not say much about the SSD this system has, but if it is recent, you can forget about wear. Recent benchmarks have shown that SSD's can be completely overwritten incessantly for months on end, 24/7, before they show any type of "wear".

That being said, `/tmp` in `tmpfs` is really a good idea (as Ignacio commented), not so much for wear reduction, more for performance reasons.